# How to display pure negative images in TensorBoard for TensorFlow object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection-api

I have changed the min_negative_per_image variable in the config to a nonzero constant according to [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3578).

```
hard_example_miner {
        num_hard_examples: 3000
        iou_threshold: 0.99
        loss_type: CLASSIFICATION
        max_negatives_per_positive: 3
        min_negatives_per_image: 3
      }
```

I have also added the non-annotated images which are the pure negative images during tfrecord generation and parsed the tfrecords generated result to check if the images were copied to tfrecords.
These are the features I have used for generating Tfrecords. These are the features I have used if the

```
tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
        'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
        'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/source_id': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
        'image/key/sha256': dataset_util.bytes_feature(key.encode('utf8')),
        'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
        'image/format': dataset_util.bytes_feature(image_format),
        'image/object/bbox/xmin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmins),
        'image/object/bbox/xmax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(xmaxs),
        'image/object/bbox/ymin': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymins),
        'image/object/bbox/ymax': dataset_util.float_list_feature(ymaxs),
        'image/object/class/text': dataset_util.bytes_list_feature(classes_text),
        'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
```

and these are the features I have used for purely negative images

```
obj_features = {
                'image/height': dataset_util.int64_feature(height),
                'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(width),
                'image/filename': dataset_util.bytes_feature(filename),
                'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
                'image/annotated': dataset_util.int64_feature(0)
        }
        tf_features = tf.train.Features(feature = obj_features)
        tf_example = tf.train.Example(features = tf_features)
```

I have parsed the tfrecords and saw that the purely negative images were present in the tfrecords. I have changed the visualization to 1000 in the config file and cannot see a single purely negative image. Is there a way to view those images in TensorBoard?

Answer (score 0):

For me, without changing the hard example mining protos and just by fixing how tfrecords are generated I was able to see negative examples when displaying the eval results on Tensorboard.

A difference I have in generate_tfrecords.py is I passed in empty lists for xmins, xmaxs, ymins, ymaxs, and so on, so perhaps that's a direction to look into.